# Scroll View does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

The scroll view does not scroll. I am coding for hours and reading the documents and can't find why it does not scroll. Any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class about: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        ScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (320,400)

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing is overlaying the scroll view and intercepts the touches?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't scroll?  Are you on a real device or simulator?  How are you trying to scroll it?

Comment: Yes nothing is overlaying and I am on a real device

Comment: And how do you know it's not scrolling?

Comment: By sight!!!! It is not moving!!!

Comment: What content is on it?  And what's the height of `self.view`?

Comment: I have text and images on the scroll view. I have updated the code that is easier but still  does not work

Comment: I don't think 400px will give you scroll. Have you tried increasing height in contentSize ? Like ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (320,600)

Comment: Yes I have done that.... I'm out of ideas..

Comment: ok the strange thing is that it goes horizontal when I set it to like (400,600) and not vertical. I have checked the Show vertical indicator

Answer (score 0):

A UIScrollView will only scroll if the height of it's `contentSize` property is larger than the view controller's bounds. Even a 3GS has a height of 480 points, so setting a height of 400 as you are doing will never make the content height large enough for it to scroll.

Try setting it to a value like 1000 (or anything larger than the screen's point size minus the status bar and navigation bar plus any other interface elements) and it should work as intended.